# Xcode Clipboard: Copy & Paste stuck

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10, xcode11, xcode9.4

I've just updated to Xcode 9.4.1 and experienced an issue with the clipboard being cleared randomly.

So I select a text, hit `CMD+C`, then go to the position I want to paste it, hit `CMD+V`, but either

- it plays the system alert sound and doesn't paste anything, or
- it pastes a previous snippet that I copied earlier.

**Update**

Still remains with Xcode 10.1

**Update 2**

Still remains with Xcode 11

Comment: I've experienced this issue numerous times with older Xcode versions as well. Not sure if it has to do anything with my clipboard manager (I'm using Copied, I used iClipboard before and the same issue occurred to me back then).

Comment: I use Alfred, but never had an issue with that before ...

Comment: @matt I know that it's a valid workaround, but I'd rather use punch cards than copying and pasting with my mouse (touchpad). I usually just copy the selected part again and it works.

Comment: @matt Because it happend right after the update of Xcode. So still programming related. Because IDE

Comment: I've just experienced this exact issue when updating to Xcode 10. I've never experienced it before. I also use Alfred.

Comment: I noticed the same problem with the Xcode 10 update. At first I thought it was me that didn't properly copied the text (even though it almost never happened before) but I just cut/paste some text and when I was about to paste it, nothing...
I checked and it was properly copied to my clipboard manager. I'm pretty positive it's an Xcode problem.

Comment: @cmlloyd @Nico If you haven't already, log out and back in. The symptoms sound like ones I've seen when `pboard` has crashed.

Comment: @Nico I also confirm that the item has successfully been copied. The strange thing is if if try and paste direct into Xcode (Cmd-V) i get the alert sound and no pasting. However, if i open Alfred clipboard history and paste from the it pastes fine.

Comment: @KenThomases Logging out didn't appear to make a lot of difference with this issue

Comment: @KenThomases loging out of?

Comment: @Nico: Out of your user account on macOS. But cmlloyd reports it didn't help.

Comment: I've bought a new keyboard because of that bug 

Comment: Eva's answer below is the fix!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Turning off the 'Automatically Sync Pasteboard' option in the Edit menu of the Simulator works for me. 
I read it in Apple forums

Comment: Thank yo so very much!!  This was driving me bat * crazy!

Comment: Still happens in Xcode 10.2.1, and this workaround seems to fix it.

Comment: In my case this didn't help. I tried several times. Enabling and disabling the sync. As soon as I hit Get Pasteboard from Edit menu, the simulator is frozen and I need to Force Close it. Xcode 10.2.1. iPhone XsMax and others.

For me the solution is: Disable Auto Sync + IMPORTANT((SHOW KEYBOARD)).  The simulator keyboard should be visible. Then it works as a workaround.

Comment: @VitoValov I disabled auto sync and show keyboard (no hardware connected) and it still hangs.

Comment: In case instead i'm NOT using simulator - in the Edit menu doesn't exist that options :( 
So i'm witing each time 1-3 minutes before to having pasted my code in the editor

Answer (score 8):

This really helps! Just uncheck the Automatically Sync Pasteboard

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also read in the Apple forums that closing the simulator while working fixes this issue. So if it happens to me I close the simulator and copy-paste works fine from that point forwards.

Haven't tried it yet but I have feeling that Eva's answer is correct in that the simulator is trying to sync your pasteboard.

[Apple forum article](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106140)

** Edit **

Can confirm that Eva's answer works and I no longer have this issue when I turn of automatic syncing on the simulator

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me. See my comment there.
The problem is with the Handoff.

I had the **Handoff** option enabled in OS X Settings > General.

After ***unchecking*** that option, I have the clipboard synced and no simulator freezes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this one:

This is the officially recommended way to reset Xcode's preferences, type in Terminal.app:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```